# C#/ASP.NET programmatically generated a select element with options

Tags: c#, mysql

I would like to generate a select box with options using C#/ASP.NET.

How would I go about doing this? I can do it in PHP or Python, however in C# I figure I have to use a .cs file?

Are there any controls I need to put on the main ASPX page?

I want to pull a list of names and ids from a MySQL database, insert the name as the option to be selected, and the id as the value, and have that all show up on the page.

I'm not sure how C# interacts between .aspx and .aspx.cs in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you would have a `Dropdownlist` control bound to a `Datasource` control in your `.aspx` page. The `Datasource` control will use a connection string you have defined in your web.config file to connect to your mysql database.

The `.aspx.cs` contains the code for when you postback to the server after, for example, selecting a name in your `Dropdownlist`. If you are using Visual Studio, most of it can be done through the UI.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
...
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.DataSource = [your data source];
ddl.Databind();
ddl.DataTextField = [field to show]
ddl.DataValueField = [value]

Page.Controls.Add(ddl);
```

Comment: if you create a DropDownList in code behind, you need also a placeholder-control to add the control to the page.

Comment: This is true (+1)... You can also just put the dropdownlist in the ASPX page as well. I was just making the point about the code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find examples here:

[DataBinding DropDownList in C#/ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071407/databinding-dropdownlist-in-c-asp-net)

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/303564/Binding-DropDownList-Using-List-Collection-Enum-an

And the basics:

http://asp.net-tutorials.com/basics/code-behind/#.UH7-zsWlXO4

And a quick example:

The aspx file:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="myDDL" runat="server" DataTextField="MyTextField" DataValueField="MyValueField" />
</div>
</form>
```

The code behind file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    myDDL.DataSource = myDataTable;
    myDDL.DataBind();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to use Checkboxlist clearly explained in this tutorial;

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-and-Repopulate-Users-selections-from-Database-using-ASP.Net-CheckBoxList.aspx